# Why is JSON from aws rds run in Docker "malformed" according to other tools?

Tags: json

To my eyes the following JSON looks valid.

```
{
    "DescribeDBLogFiles": [
        {
            "LogFileName": "error/postgresql.log.2022-09-14-00",
            "LastWritten": 1663199972348,
            "Size": 3032193
        }
    ]
}
```

**A) But,** `jq`, `json_pp`, and Python `json.tool` module deem it **invalid**:

```bash
# jq 1.6
> echo "$logfiles" | jq  
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 2

# json_pp 4.02
> echo "$logfiles" | json_pp
malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, 
at character offset 0 (before "\x{1b}[?1h\x{1b}=\r{...") at /usr/bin/json_pp line 51

> python3 -m json.tool <<< "$logfiles"
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

**B) But on the other hand,** if the above JSON is copy & pasted into an online validator, both [1](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) and [2](https://jsonlint.com), deem it **valid**.

---

As hinted by `json_pp`'s error above, `hexdump <<< "$logfiles"` indeed shows additional, surrounding characters. Here's the prefix: `5b1b 313f 1b68 0d3d 1b7b ....`, where `7b` is `{`.

---

The JSON is output to a `logfiles` variable by this command:

```
logfiles=$(aws rds describe-db-log-files \
  --db-instance-identifier somedb \
  --filename-contains 2022-09-14)

# where `aws` is
alias aws='docker run --rm -it -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws amazon/aws-cli:2.7.31'
```

```bash
> bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

---

Have perused [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/501), yet can't figure out the cause. I suspect that double quotes get mangled somehow when using `echo` - some reported that `printf` "worked" for them.

Comment: Apparently your variable begins: `\x{1b}[?1h\x{1b}=\r{` and not `{`. Some sort of escape sequence.

Comment: Indeed, `hexdump <<< "$logfiles"'` confirms this: `5b1b 313f 1b68 0d3d 1b7b ....`, where `7b` is `{`. The "undesired" sequence is also present as a suffix, after the ending `}\n`: `5b1b 0d6d 0d0a 5b1b 1b4b 3f5b 6c31 3e1b 000a`. If anyone has a clue on what might be producing these, please post a comment or an answer. I'll look into `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: probably `aws rds ...` is adding ANSI colour codes

Comment: what happens if you add `--color off` and/or `--output json` ? https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-log-files.html

Comment: disabling pagination might have an effect too

Comment: @jhnc thanks for the hints! Sadly, none of `--output json --color off --no-paginate` help. The `hexdump` of `logfiles=$(aws ...  --output json --color off --no-paginate)` still contains the surrounding, prefix and suffix, characters.

Comment: It could be `docker run` that is doing it. Do you need `-it` ?

Comment: Bingo! Removing `-it` also removed the unwanted sequences. If you'll post an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @VanillaDonuts Do you mind editing the details in your first comment into the question itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `docker run --rm -it -v` command to produce the JSON, added some additional unprintable characters to the start of the JSON data. That makes the resulting file `$logfiles` invalid.

The -t option allocations a tty and the -i creates an interactive shell. In this case the -t is allowing the shell to read login scripts (e.g. `.bashrc`). Something in your start up scripts is outputting ansi escape codes. Often this will to clear the screen, set up other things for the interactive shell, or make the output more visually appealing by colorizing portions of the data.